# Add a border to an irregular shaped image

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to develop a company's team page that uses an irregular-shaped png image but needs to have a red border around the image.

The finished product needs to look like the following:
[image]

The image I was given is this:
[image]

Is there a way using css/js to give the image a border that stays right on the area where the irregular shape is?

Have searched high and low but could not find a workable solution.

Comment: Will this border change color on hover or something ...? If not, make it in photoshop...

Comment: Add the border using a photo-editing software, because that image is actually rectangular

Comment: The goal would obviously be to use a hover state that could change the border color. Just looking to see if it is possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Border on PNG image with transparent parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690444/css-border-on-png-image-with-transparent-parts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to **remove the the white unused space to alpha channel** using an image editor and save it as a **.png** file then you can make use of drop shadow to apply the desired effect. The following is just a demonstration:

```css
img {
  width: 70%;
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 0px 0 red);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s7.postimg.org/65lydsb57/a_Ql6e.png">
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Was not familiar with drop-shadow but that is brilliant.

Comment: It's one of the filter properties available in CSS3.