# FabricJS Rendering a shadow around active object/selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

Quick and simple: Is there a way that I can achieve the following effect after clicking on an active FabricJS element or active selection? Basically, as well as the border, I'd like to render a shadow/border effect around the active elements. Once you click away, the shadow will be removed.

**Example code:** *(sourced from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28255938/13531218)*)

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black)
                  drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) 
          drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
}

body {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/GZoXRjS.png" width="250">
```

Comment: Do you need the full flexibility of shadows from CSS, or could you get by using the `fabric.Shadow` class (http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Shadow.html)?  If you just need simple shadows, you could add an event listener for selection/deselection to add/remove the shadow from the selected object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to use fabricjs events and set or unset the shadow on the image object.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://i.imgur.com/GZoXRjS.png', function(img) {
img.scaleToWidth(500)

canvas.add(img)

img.on('deselected',function(e){
    this.set('shadow', null);
})
});


canvas.on('object:selected',function(e){
debugger;
  if(e && e.target){
    e.target.set('shadow', { blur: 15, offsetX: 0, offsetY: 0});
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.15/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas width=800 height=800 id="c" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Any way to get this to work with an active selection of objects?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Using eventListener on the body element.

- When the Image was clicked checking by the **tagName** then the css styles will be applied.
- When the body was clicked then the applied styling will be reset using the attribute value none

In the snippet you can see the behavior

```js
let pic = document.getElementById("demo-pic");

document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
    pic.setAttribute(
      "style",
      "-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black)drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);"
    );
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightcoral";
  } else if (e.target.tagName === "BODY") {
    pic.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter: none;");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="fabric.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mydemo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <img id="demo-pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/GZoXRjS.png" width="250">
    <script src="mydemoFile.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using the `focus` pseudo element like this in conjunction with an `a` tag could achieve what you are looking for.

Take a look here:

```css
a:focus img{
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black)
                  drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) 
          drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
}

body {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GZoXRjS.png" width="250">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css).

if you give your `img` tag a `tabindex` then you can use the `focus` psuedo class to simulate a click.

however i had to remove the `outline`:

```css
img:focus {
  outline:0;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black)
                  drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) 
          drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
}
body {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/GZoXRjS.png" width="250" tabindex="0">
```