# How to add border to the image as polygon/round shaped

Tags: fabricjs

We are building the shapes for conveyors, Is there any way to create a **rounded border** for the images? The below images, which are png files, have square borders around the selected Images.
While Searching we found this code from the link

[CSS Border on PNG image with transparent parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690444/css-border-on-png-image-with-transparent-parts)

```
img{
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
    filter:drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
}
```

Is there any way to add drop-shadow to the images in canvas?
Kindly help us with relevant codes and suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by the properties shadow and strokeWidth(in css by adding shadow). So that image will be like this.

```
item.strokeWidth = 15;               
item.shadow = new fabric.Shadow({color:'red',blur:15,affectStroke:true});
```

**Present Output:**

[image]

If someone has a better solution kindly brainstorm me.