# How to draw a border around a semitransparent image? (css)

Tags: css, image, png, border

I was wondering how to draw a border around an image that is semitransparent, that is, I do not want a box-shaped border, nor a border radius, but a border that actually applies to the shape of the image itself.

According to [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690444/css-border-on-png-image-with-transparent-parts) it's not possible, and [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795196/how-do-i-use-css-to-add-a-non-%20rectangular-border-around-an-image) simply suggest to edit the image in some photo editing program such as Photoshop.

But what if the image input isn't mine? If I needed to process a series of user-inputed images to my website and add that border, the software option wouldn't work.

One way to tackle that would be to use canvas, but isn't there a pure, simple, css way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: This still is a duplicate question.

Comment: @web-tiki It's not, mine is better formulated and would probably match closer to what someone with this problem would search, "*if those answers do not fully answer your questions..ask a new question*", well they didn't, so can you undo that?

Comment: the question is the same as the duplicate : *"adding border around a  semi transparent image"*. Adding your answer there is better than asking a new one to post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of now (*January 31st 2015*) there is a way to do that without using canvas, with pure CSS, and with only 2 lines of code.

The trick is using the css `filter` and `-webkit-filter` properties to draw two drop shadows with no blur, one for the positive axis and one for the negative, which will wrap around the image, which will provide the (*hopefully*) desired effect.

**Note**: css filters are not at all supported in IE (let's hope Spartan does better), here is a [**compatibility table**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). (Thanks [**web-tiki**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki))

This first snippet ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpdvmhcm/2/)) will apply the **simplest border possible**.

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black)
                  drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) 
          drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
}

body {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju44K.jpg" width="250">
```

As you can see, some images (like [**this awesome baymax render**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju44K.jpg)) need a little more tweaking, you can see the right border is a little smaller than the left.

With that in mind, here is the **perfected border snippet** ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpdvmhcm/1/)) with just a really tiny value tweak.

```css
img {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 1px 0 black)
                  drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 1px 0 black) 
          drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 black);
}

body {
  background-color: khaki;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju44K.jpg" width="250">
```

That should cover borders pretty well, but we can still have more fun with this, look at this awesome **lightness effect snippet** ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mpdvmhcm/6/)).

```css
img{
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) 
                    drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 white);
    filter:drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 black) 
           drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 white);
}

body{
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju44K.jpg" width="250">
```

Hope this helps anyone wondering about the possibility of a wrap-around border for semitransparent images!

Comment: Intersting, although you should specify that the `filter` property has the "working draft" status and that IE doesn't support it at all.

Comment: I would suggest you add your answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: @web-tiki added a note with informing about the ie problem and posted my answers in both other questions, although I really don't think mine is a duplicate :)

Comment: this drop-shadow is awesome, thanks a lot~